# Distinguish two header files with same name using cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cygwin

I have the following situation using cmake

1. Running windows 7
2. Both cygwin and visual studio (VS) community edition (version 14) installed
3. Cygwin has winsock2.h in /usr/include/w32api
4. The VS community edition does not have winsock2.h
5. Note that some older (non community edition) versions of VS do have
   winsock2.h defined.
6. CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE("winsock2.h", HAVE_WINSOCK2_H) returns true
   because it is finding the cygwin version instead of the VS version.

The question is how do I see if the installed VS has winsock2.h defined
while ignoring any cygwin version.

The reason I need to know this is that the presence of winsock2.h
in VS is causing a conflict with another package (libcurl). I can
work around the conflict if I know if the VS installation has
winsock2.h (or not).

I speculate that I need to prevent CMake from searching
w32api. A possible complexity is that I might have to specify
the actual windows file system path to the cywin /usr/include/w32api.
That is, I might have to specify something like c:/cygwin/usr/include/w32api
and it is not obvious how to get that revised path.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES` variable before calling `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE`?

Comment: Or use `if(NOT MINGW)`.

Comment: I hypothesize the problem is the same with  MINGW since w32api will still be there and I might have both VS and MINGW installed.

Comment: I considered  CMAKE_REQUIRED_INClUDES, but in this case it looks like I need to remove a directory (/usr/include/w32api) and I can see no way to do that. So perhaps the question should be: how do I use CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES to remove/disable searching a specific directory